# Change the next N characters in VIM

Tags: vim, character

Say I have the following line:

```
|add_test()          (| == cursor position)
```

And want to replace the 'add' with a 'del'.

```
del|_test()
```

I can either press X three times and then press i to insert and type del.
What I want is something like 3c or 3r to overwrite just 3 characters.
Both of these don't do what I want, 3c overwrites 3 characters with the same
character, 3r does several other things.

Is there an easy way to do this without manually Xing and inserting the text?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

`3s`, "substitute 3 characters" is the same as `c3l`.  `3cl` and `c3l` should be the same, I don't know why you'd see the same character repeated.  I'm also a fan of using `t`, e.g. `ct_` as another poster mentioned, then I don't have to count characters and can just type "del".

I struggled with the "replace a couple of characters" for a few days too; 'r' was great for single characters, `R` was great for a string of matching length, but I wanted something like the OP is asking for.  So, I typed `:help x` and read for a while, it turns out that the description of `s` and `S` are just a couple of pages down from `x`.

In other words, `:help` is your friend.  Read and learn.

Comment: It would be great if after typing "3s" and having typed 3 characters, it would automatically go back in Normal mode. I wonder if there is a way to do something like that (similarly to `3r`)

Comment: Yeah I've often wanted such a thing too. Alas, I don't know of it if it exists.

Comment: I don't see why this answer got so many upvotes. A good answer should give a concise solution to the question, not speak in generalities like "help is your friend"

Answer (score 32):

Use **c{motion}** command:

1. **cf_** - change up to the first '_' (including);
2. **ct_** - change up to the first '_' (excluding);
3. **cw**  - change the first word;

The word is determined by **iskeyword** variable. Check it with **:set iskeyword?** and remove any '_', like that **:set iskeyword=@,48-57,192-255**.
By the way see **:help c** and **:help motion** if you want more.

Comment: ct_ is actually better than what I was looking for, but technically the s command answers the question ;-)

Comment: This is the better answer. Although OP was changing 3 chars in his example, this answer addresses changing N chars in any word.

Answer (score 10):

I think `3cl` is what you want.  It changes 3 characters to the right.  I'd type `ct_del<esc>`, but that's not what you asked

Answer (score 8):

`c3`  ('c', '3', space), then type the characters you want to insert.  (Or you can use right-arrow or `l` rather than space.)

Or, as @Mike just said in a comment, `R` works nicely if the number of characters happens to match the number of characters you're deleting.

Or `ct_` to change from the cursor to the next `_` character.

Or, as @bloody suggests in a comment, `3s`.

Comment: Now that I think about it isn't it capital R rather than CTRL+R?

Comment: Nice! Didn't know about the option of using «space» before.

Comment: This is very slow in vim (*space* is somehow processed for a long time). What is more `3s` is still shorter, faster and obvious if you know that `s` changes the current character.

Comment: @bloody `3s` is a good suggestion, but `c3 ` isn't slow on my system.

Answer (score 5):

If the works have the same length you can use the `R` command which replaces what you had previously with what you type.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers given use numbers. When the text is longer it's easier to not have to count. For example I often make headlines in markdown files like:

`Some super duper long title that I don't want to have to count`

double the line with `yy` `pp`

`Some super duper long title that I don't want to have to count
Some super duper long title that I don't want to have to count`

Highlighth the whole line with `V`
then use `r{char}` or in this case `r=` to get:

`Some super duper long title that I don't want to have to count
 ==============================================================`

(I added a space above to trip stack overflow's markdown formatting)

Comment: this answer can be presented in a better way